# jquery bindings are conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

How would I rewrite this code so that the bindings don't conflict? I have a scale on hover effect that stops responding once I click on the target picture (to reveal a Youtube video).

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
//to scale up on hover
$('#videoandmapwrap').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: (current_w * 2.7),
            height: (current_h * 2.7)
        }, 900);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: current_w + 'px',
            height: current_h + 'px'
        }, 400);
    }
}, 'img');

//to reveal from behind placeholder picture
   $('#videoandmapwrap').on("click","img",function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
      video = '<iframe class="piccon" width="200" height="200" src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
      $(this).replaceWith(video);  
   });

     </script>
```

Comment: I was lead to believe rewriting the code using event delegation would solve the problem but it hasn't! thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its because of this line:

```
$(this).replaceWith(video);
```

basically you are replacing the #videoandmapwrap with the iframe you created, so your original content and its attached events are gone.   try popping that video up in another element instead of the one you clicked on

Comment: I see, once I click there is no longer an img -- its replaced with the iframe. I repeated the code and changed all the img to iframe and it got the job done! thank you so much erikrunia!